# How can I test if a variable is set using typeof?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to use typeof to determine whether or not a variable is undefined:

```
function reset_textarea(reset) {

if (typeof(reset) != 'undefined') {
   ...do stuff
  }

}
```

Im calling it like this:

```
reset_textarea('hello');
```

Its not working and I can't seem to figure out why. The function fires normally if I remove the if statement, thus - the issue seems to lie in the way I am testing whether or not the variable is set. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: 139 questions and the only explanation in the question is "Its not working". Define "not working". "Any idea what is going on?" -- the code works as expected

Comment: I normally do `if (reset) {
   ...do stuff
  }` which works if reset is not null, undefined, blank or 0

Comment: As @zerkms states, there's nothing wrong with what you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tCFCJ/

Comment: Could it be that this is IE and there is something called reset somewhere on the page? Or that reset is semi-reserved word in the browser you have?

Comment: No, its not IE, nor is it a reserved word because I have tried other variable names. The code runs in isolation - there is no other js on the page.

Comment: Are you checking that the *argument* isn't "unusable", or that a global variable is not `undefined`?

Comment: Also, questions shouldn't have the tags (e.g. Javascript) in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `typeof("hello")` (type of *string*) is defined. It's a `String`. `typeof(hello)` (note missing quotes) is what you need. Does this work for you?

```
if(typeof(window[reset]) !== 'undefined') {
  //...
}
```

You must understand the difference between a variable (`hello`) and a string (`"hello"`). Remember that `window["hello"]` is equivalent to `window.hello`, but more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for the existence of a property with the specified name on `window`:

```
function reset_textarea(reset) {

    if (typeof(window[reset]) !== 'undefined') {
       // ...do stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using `window` would work until some context for the function execution is specified

Comment: Two answers mentioning `window[reset]`, when `reset` is an argument. What am I missing?

Comment: @JaredFarrish given `reset = "hello"`, `window[reset]` is the same as writing `window.hello`, I.E. access a global variable by the name `hello`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I assumed the OP is trying to use the contents of `reset` to identify a variable.

Comment: @Esailija: and how did you get OP needs that? I've read the question about 5 times for now and still cannot see it :-S

Comment: @zerkms I don't really know what the OP really wants, just explaining what this code is doing :-)

Comment: @Esailija - Actually, maybe I don't get it. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tCFCJ/1/ Now maybe there's two different interpretations, one being that the *argument* isn't `undefined`, the other being a *global* variable isn't? Is that right? I think the former is what the OP wants; what's the point of the latter?

Comment: Well if we assume it's former, then his code works fine. Then again, I cannot know anything because the OP is withholding any useful info on the problem. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: So, Im trying to use the function in to different cases. The reset variable is actually just a boolean. The value of the variable is inconsequential.

Comment: No, it's a string. You pass a string. The if condition will evaluate to true, because string is not undefined. Then what happens?

Comment: I know that it isn't an actual boolean, but I was unsure how to pass an actual boolean to the function so Im attempting to simply detect whether or not a variable set. I plan on using the value of the string later on anyways but for the time being it simply acts a boolean.

Comment: @Thomas You could make a jsfiddle. FWIW, both of the answers you got so far are way off if you were planning to use `reset` as a boolean, since it wouldn't make sense to use a boolean to look up global variables. You will most likey not get a satisfactory answer until you provide sufficient information. What happens? What is expected to happen? And what is the full code?

Comment: @Esailija - Personally, I think there's something else going on here that's just not depicted, and the line of error hasn't been determined accurately by the OP. Not like that's ever happened before.